# Unable to read TLD "META-INF/tld/tiles-jsp.tld"

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, tiles

I made a jsp file using tiles and springframework, but I have been unable to read TLD "META-INF/tld/tiles-jsp.tld".

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a jsp-api JAR in your WEB-INF/lib folder, remove it.

This fixed the problem for me. [via](http://old.nabble.com/Unable-to-read-TLD-td13396176.html)